# Flask-based webapp creates xlsx file and should have it downloadable over ajax/

Tags: python, ajax, post, flask, xlsx

Currently I have a webapp that creates file based on data users provide. The generate part is finished and working. For pdf & csv files, my download code works. But for some reason, xlsx files are not downloading.

I simplified my code:
this ajax call is in a clicklistener for a button that calls a flask method. I found the succes part somewhere on stack and I was very happy it worked for pdf/csv.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "{{ url_for('downloadxls') }}",
        method: "POST", data: {
            #data #not including in my example
        },
        success: function(response, status, xhr) {
            var filename = "";
            var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
            if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
            }

            var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
            var blob = new Blob([response], { type: type });

            if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
            } else {
                var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                if (filename) {
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                window.location = downloadUrl;
            } else {
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            }
        } else {
            window.location = downloadUrl;
        }

        setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
    }
}
});
```

here is my flask method.

```
@app.route('/downloadxls', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def downloadxls():
     #generation of xlx file. this is working since i see the file on my system. for pdf and csv i do similar things to create the file.
        xls = generate_report_xls.generate(list_sensors,list_x_lists,list_y_lists,events_ndb,story,current_user)
        return send_file('../'+xls, mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
```

the things is, when I scan my network traffic while performing the POST. I can see that the xlsx file in the response. It is just not downloading..

any help?
sorry for the long code parts, i tried to simplify them

Answer (score -1):

You don't need ajax request to download file. There are lots of examples around internet, I think this is simplest.

https://gist.github.com/DavidMah/3533415

Method is simple. Make temporary form, submit form, and remove it.

Every modern browsers can handles file download without page move.

Comment: but i need ajax to call the flask method (server side)